# Hibernate query with join over ElementCollection does not work

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, join, hql

I'm trying to make a Hibernate query (JPA over Hibernate). Consider a very simple entity model: an entity called `DocumentedObject` that has an `ElementCollection` of `UserHistoryObject` (named `personInChargeHistory`). I want to find `DocumentedObjects` that have some special `User` in their history by HQL. Trying the the query:

```
select d from DocumentedObject as d join d.personInChargeHistory as ph where ph.value.id=:some_userid
```

It results in:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property: value.id of: DocumentedObject [select distinct d from DocumentedObject as d join d.personInChargeHistory as ph  where ph.value.id=2 ]
```

The only problem I could think is that UsrHistoryObject is embeddable. But if this is the problem how should I make such query? Here are my entities:

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
public class DocumentedObject {

    private Long id;
    private List<UserHistoryObject> personInChargeHistory = new LinkedList<UserHistoryObject>();

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @ElementCollection
    @OrderBy("date desc")
    public List<UserHistoryObject> getPersonInChargeHistory() {
        return personInChargeHistory;
    }

    public void setPersonInChargeHistory(List<UserHistoryObject> personInChargeHistory) {
        this.personInChargeHistory = personInChargeHistory;
    }

}

@Embeddable
public class UserHistoryObject {

    private Date date;
    private User value;

    public UserHistoryObject() {
    }

    public UserHistoryObject(Date date, User value) {
        this.date = date;
        this.value = value;
    }

    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    public Date getDate() {
        return date;
    }

    public void setDate(Date date) {
        this.date = date;
    }

    @ManyToOne
    public User getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(User value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
}

@Entity
public class User {

    private Long id;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
}
```

Comment: Does creating a default constructor for `DocumentedObject` help? In the constructor of `UserHistoryObject` you make the assignment `this.user = user;`, but there exists no attribute `user`?!

Comment: can you share your user class. Does that User class has field id ?

Comment: I added definition of `User` entity and constructor of UserHistoryObject is also corrected. There were some mistakes because of copy-paste from real code :)

Comment: Default constructors for `DocumentedObject` and `User` are still missing.

Comment: Strangely editing the query like this works `select d from DocumentedObject as d join d.personInChargeHistory as ph where ph.value=:some_user`, i.e. using the `user` as the parameter instead of `user.id`

Answer (score 2):

It looks like querying through Element collections of Embeddables is a little bit neglected in JPA. I checked the specification and is says nothing explicit about supporting Path expressions for them.

I search Hibernate bug database and found no bug reported with your specific issue. The closest one suggesting problems with Element collections of Embeddables is this one:
https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-8926

With Eclipselink situation looks a bit better, because EclipseLink supports this type of queries from version 2.4.0.